# JSON Object (Being Looped to query the data) Not returning the Data BUT IS showing record is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

So here's a weird one for you...

As you see below, I have created code to inject content into a modal (using Bootstrap) which comes from a local JSON object and is dependent on the button which has been clicked.

However, the content which should be injected is not being injected! Despite this, I DO know that the if statement IS having it's conditions met on one of the loops thanks to my console.log commands dotted around the place, specifically in the loop and the if function(within the loop too).

Attached image shows the console log and modal at work.(Red writing is composited on the screenshot, not live ;) ) [image]

Heres the Javascript (navigation.js):

```
$('#projectModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Define Button which triggered Modal
    var inputTitle = button.data('title'); // Extract data-title attribute value
    console.log(inputTitle);

    // Generate JSON Database
    var json = [{prTitle:"Forever Fitness Gibraltar", prDescription:"This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today.", prClient:"Tonu Osa", prWorkers:"Anton Brink, Paula Osa", prLocation:"Tallinn, Estonia", prDuration:"4 Weeks"},
            {prTitle:"The Spy Program", prDescription:"This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today.", prClient:"Skye", prWorkers:"Anton Brink, Paula Osa", prLocation:"London, England", prDuration:"2 Weeks"},
            {prTitle:"Leeds Fest", prDescription:"This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today.", prClient:"Leeds Dude", prWorkers:"Anton Brink, Paula Osa, Oliver Brink", prLocation:"Leeds, England", prDuration:"1 Week"}
        ];

    // For Testing Purposes only, the loop is not currently declaring any values from the JSON database -.-
    var description = 'This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today. This description should be extremely long but I cannot be arsed to write much today.';
    var client = 'Skye';
    var workers = 'Anton Brink, Paula Osa';
    var location = 'London, England';
    var duration = '2 Weeks';

    // Loop to Find JSON data corresponding to data-title
    $.each(json, function(n, v) {
        console.log('In');
        if(v.prTitle == inputTitle) {
            console.log('Looping');
            var description = v.prDescription;
            var client = v.prClient;
            var workers = v.prWorkers;
            var location = v.prLocation;
            var duration = v.prDuration;
            return;
        }
    });

    console.log(description);
    console.log(client);
    console.log(workers);
    console.log(location);
    console.log(duration);

    var modal = $(this);

    // Inject relevant JSON data into Modal Contents
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(inputTitle); // Inject Title directly from inputTitle attribute
    modal.find('#projectModalDescription').text(description);
    modal.find('#projectModalDetailsClient').text(client);
    modal.find('#projectModalDetailsWorkers').text(workers);
    modal.find('#projectModalDetailsLocation').text(location);
    modal.find('#projectModalDetailsDuration').text(duration);

});
```

Here's the HTML for the Modal:

```
<div id="projectModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Awesome Project!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <p id="projectModalDescription">
                            Nothing in here yet, stupid JSON Object... WORK!
                            <br />
                            Signed,
                            <br />
                            Mech
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- .col-* -->
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h5 id="projectModalDetailsHeader">The Specs</h5>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Client</h6>
                                <p id="projectModalDetailsClient" class="list-group-item-text">Nothing</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Project Mates</h6>
                                <p id="projectModalDetailsWorkers" class="list-group-item-text">In</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Location</h6>
                                <p id="projectModalDetailsLocation" class="list-group-item-text">Here</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Duration</h6>
                                <p id="projectModalDetailsDuration" class="list-group-item-text">Yet -.-</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .col-* -->
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- .modal-body -->
        </div><!-- .modal-content -->
    </div><!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- #projectModal -->
```

And for the buttons:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectModal" data-title="Forever Fitness Gibraltar">Click me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectModal" data-title="The Spy Program">Click me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectModal" data-title="Leeds Fest">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data structure it is hard to help with full solution.

However your `each` loop isn't right. You are declaring local variables inside that loop that can't be accessed outside the callback.

Also, each iteration of the loop will overwrite those variables

```
var description = "Original";

$.each(json, function(n, v) {
       // this is different variable than the one above
       var description = "New Description";
});
console.log(description)// "Original"
```

Use variables from above loop (still will only get value of last iteration)

```
$.each(json, function(n, v) {
       // this is same variable as above
        description = "New Description";
});
console.log(description)// "New Description"
```

Need more understanding of data or reason for loop to help more

Comment: The JSON object is declared just above the loop? However, your insight as to the local variables not being available perfectly explains my dilemma. What I am looking to do is return only one record from that JSON "database" for want of another word. Basically, how do I get those variables accessible for further use after the loop?